# Has anyone written a Session Monitor for Intraweb?

Tags: delphi, intraweb

I am thinking of writing a session monitor (or manager) for my Intraweb application that would list the current active sessions and allow the user to terminate any of those sessions.  Does anyone has source code for this already?  I saw that ArcanaTech.com had a product called Intraweb Server Manager at one time that looks like it did exactly what I am looking for.  However, they seem to have disappeared after 2007 and the product doesn't seem to be available anywhere.

Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Dean Millam

Comment: In case you were willing to consider an alternative: Because I was looking for a way do build web-applications with Delphi, and was not content with IntraWeb and other options, I have started this project: http://xxm.sourceforge.net/ It takes a radically different approach and mimics the combination of HTML and code like PHP and ASP uses, and auto-compilation behind the scenes. I know, it's new, really basic, but it's built for speed, performance and small footprint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an IwtraWeb ServerManager which includes Session management for "adminitrators". ServerManager has originally been developed as commercial component by Arcana Technologies, but is now available under open source, as part of the [IWElite package](http://code.google.com/p/iwelite/).